# Update image with information in php

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I've been looking for a code to update my image from the database from youtube and here in stackoverflow. But I cant seem to make it work. The image can get updated but the title and the body cannot be edited. please help.

im usig it with php and phpmyadmin

this is the code i've been trying to make the update:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

 $id = $_POST['editid'];
 $edtitle = $_POST['edittitle'];
 $edbody = $_POST['editmyTextarea'];
 $file = $_FILES['editpgupload'];

 $filename = $file['name'];
 $fileTmp = $file['tmp_name'];
 $filesize = $file['size'];
 $fileerror = $file['error'];
 $filetype = $file['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $filename);
$fileActExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

if (in_array($fileActExt, $allowed)) {
  if ($fileerror === 0) {
    if ($filesize < 1000000) {
      $filenamenew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActExt;
      $fileds = '../../../image/upload/'.$filenamenew;
      move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileds);

      $sql = "UPDATE patients_guide SET pg_title = '$edtitle', pg_body = '$edbody', pg_image = '$filenamenew' WHERE pg_id = '$id'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      header("Location: ../index.php?update=success");
    }else{
      // echo "your image is too large";
      header("Location: ../index.php?error=imagetoolarge");
    }

  }else{
    // echo "There was an error uploading your file";
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=errorupload");
  }

}else{
  // echo "You can not upload this file";
  header("Location: ../index.php?error=cannotupload");
}
}
```

it only updates the image but the title and the body stay the same. it cannot be edited. this should be able to update the title, body and the image.

patients_guide structure

```
   CREATE TABLE `patients_guide` (
 `pg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pg_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `pg_body` text NOT NULL,
 `pg_image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
```

Comment: First of all I would strongly recommend to use prepared statements. And I have a question: why did you decide that other fields did not get updated?

Comment: @Alex i want them to be updated to. but my codes only updates the image. i want the title and the body to be updated too

Comment: Try checking wether or not `$edtitle` and `$edbody` is not null. You can `echo` them to see what they contain. Maybe you have the wrong keys in their respective `$_POST`s?

Comment: @Yuko Thank you :) I already Got it

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -2):

I got it.

For someone that has the same problem as me here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$id = $_POST['editid'];
$edtitle = $_POST['edittitle'];
$edbody = $_POST['editmyTextarea'];
$file = $_FILES['editpgupload'];

$filename = $file['name'];
$fileTmp = $file['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $file['size'];
$fileerror = $file['error'];
$filetype = $file['type'];

//remove old image
unlink('../../../image/upload/'.$row['pg_image']);

$fileExt = explode('.', $filename);
$fileActExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

if (in_array($fileActExt, $allowed)) {
  if ($fileerror === 0) {
    if ($filesize < 1000000) {
      $filenamenew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActExt;
      $fileds = '../../../image/upload/'.$filenamenew;
      move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileds);

      $sql = "UPDATE patients_guide SET pg_title = '$edtitle', pg_body = '$edbody', pg_image = '$filenamenew' WHERE pg_id = '$id'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


      header("Location: ../index.php?update=success");
    }else{
      // echo "your image is too large";
      header("Location: ../index.php?error=imagetoolarge");
    }

  }else{
    // echo "There was an error uploading your file";
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=errorupload");
  }

}else{
  $sql = "UPDATE patients_guide SET pg_title = '$edtitle', pg_body = '$edbody' WHERE pg_id = '$id'";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


      header("Location: ../index.php?update=success");
}
}
```